# Powershell environment variables are not updated

Tags: powershell

I've have wix installer that updates environment variable using `<Environment />` element.

The environment variable value is updated in registry. But when I try to open Powershell it doesn't see any changes unless I reboot my PC.

Does anyone have any thoughts about why/how and how can I avoid reboot.
Thanks in advance,
nomail

**Update**: I've found why this is happening. It turns out that the session variables are updated on reboot or if a system broadcast message is sent.
To send a broadcast message

```
SendMessage (HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)"Environment");
```

Another dirty way to send a message is to use `SETX` command that will write new value to environment variables and update session info

```
SETX something_that_is_not_important value_that_is_not_important
```

Mind you that you will still have to close and open CommandLine or PowerShell console

Comment: Note that broadcast message works only for processes that process it. `Explorer.exe` is the only common such process. Thus any new processes created by Explorer will have the updated environment, other processes already running before the broadcast will generally not be updated.

Comment: Updating the environment via the the control panel applet (System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables) broadcasts the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message. This is why a new PowerShell or cmd shell will pickup environment changes using that tool. As @Richard says, this broadcast is understood and propagated because it's happening within the Explorer.exe shell.

The registry editor, or other tool to inject new environment variables into the registry, have no method to force the update.

So your option #1 of sending the broadcast message is viable and I wouldn't consider it "dirty".

Comment: Yep, the first option is the proper way of propagating environment variables. I meant that the second option is a 'dirty hack' which I must admit I used once.

Comment: Starting with 3.10 WIX has CustomAction `WixBroadcastSettingChange`. Which does the job.
 You use it like `<CustomActionRef Id="WixBroadcastSettingChange" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly because of a missing a `<WriteEnvironmentStrings>` element in the `<InstallExecuteSequence>` section of your WIX file.   That custom action is responsible for sending the broadcast WM_SETTINGSCHANGE message.

This isn't exactly a bug in the WIX, rather a poorly documented requirement.   To effectively use WIX you also have to understand the Windows Installer Database reference docs, not just the XML.   In the MSDN topic on the [Environment Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa368369.aspx) the need to invoke the WriteEnvironmentStrings and RemoveEnvironmentStrings custom actions is described, but in terminology that may be foreign to someone without native MSI background.

An article showing this is at http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/03/28/from-msi-to-wix-part-13-installable-items-environment-variable.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, my experiences writing [this installer](https://github.com/pololu/p-load/blob/master/windows_installer/p-load.wxs) do not match what you are claiming.  Even though I was using WriteEnvironmentStrings, I still had to add a custom action that broadcasts the message, or else the thing I added to the PATH would not be picked up by new Command Prompts after the installer is done.  The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372883) does say WriteEnvironmentSettings broadcasts that message though.  Hmm.

Comment: I don't understand what happened in your case David.   Could it have been related to system vs. user environment strings, and permissions used when installing?

Answer (score 1):

seems to be a specific wix problem, see comments at the bottom of : [this page](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/03/28/from-msi-to-wix-part-13-installable-items-environment-variable.aspx)

Comment: It's not exactly a WIX problem. It's the way the environment variables are loaded. They don't refer to registry directly rather are loaded during system start.